# Initialize a vector with '*'(special character) and then print it

Tags: c++, vector

I want to initialize a vector with a special characters and then print it

this is the code I m using

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::vector<char> p { *,*,*,*,*,*,* };

for( std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = p.begin(); i != p.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

I know I m missing something, but just cant figure out what.
I would appreciate some suggestions

Comment: Character literals need to be enclosed with apostrophes: `'*'`

Comment: You forgot to tell us what's wrong. And there's really nothing "special" about `*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::vector<char> p(7, '*');
```

would be most natural to me.

There's also

```
std::fill_n(back_inserter(p), 7, '*');
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @sehe's excellent answer would be to use a `string` instead of a `vector`:

```
std::string p = "*******";
```

I'd also use a range-based for loop if possible:

```
for (auto ch : p)
    std::cout << ch << ' ';
```

If you cant' use that, I'd generally prefer `std::copy`, something like:

```
std::copy(p.begin(), p.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: Why not `std::string p(7, '*')` though :) +1 (I didn't mention it, because the question couldn't be more clear that a vector is specifically desired, but yeah, I'd use string here too)

Comment: @sehe: No particular reason not to. Which is preferable tends to depend on the situation. If the count is important, then `(7, '*')` works well. If you want (for example) underlining to match the length of a label, it can be easier to use a literal, and (for example) put the two on consecutive lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a version with initializer lists:

```
std::vector<char> p { '*','*','*','*','*','*','*' };
```

Alternatively, you can use constructor:

```
std::vector<char> p(7, '*');
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector